# Allow review items to be filtered by watched tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, tag-watching, filtering

It would be nice to get items to review (first posts/late answers) based on watched tags (previously called favorite tags).

It's hard to review and improve questions that are from a totally unknown area. If I'm interested in Java I should not review questions about C# or PHP.

You [can provide tags to filter but max 3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234879/165773), which is a bit too limiting. Using watched tags would make reviewed items more relevant to the reviewer.

Comment: Actually I don't see a reason yet why 3 is too limiting. You could change them over time if you run out of things to review.

Comment: For example, I'm interested in JEE and related technologies - but just for ejb there are at least 3 tags - ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1, very similar for servlets or jee. So basically I cant do any reviews, since after I change the tags there are no more questions to review...