# What motivates users to review? How can they benefit from it?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, gamification

I've recently gained the privilege to review posts.

But when I do the work, I found that there are posts about things that I'm not familiar with. And then there are also *audits*, testing to see whether I'm paying attention.

So, I find the work frustrating, and not inspiring.

Which makes me wonder, what motivates users to review? How do they benefit from this?

Comment: BADGES. SHINY SHINY BADGES!!! But in all seriousness, reviewing helps to keep the site  you use on a daily basis somewhat clean. So at the end you actually want to keep using it.

Comment: I filter for tags on most review queue's, keeps the questions relevant towards what I know and makes the test questions too easy to recognize.

Comment: I share your frustration - suggested once to filter review (at least for First Posts/Late answers) using favorite tags - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262383/could-a-review-items-be-filtered-by-favorite-tags but...

Comment: @Twelfth If you're saying you filter these, I suppose you're just looking at the newest questions (as I do also). The OP's question refers to the [Review Page](http://stackoverflow.com/review) where you can't filter besides for the close votes queue.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - OP was mentioning that he is reviewing questions about things he isn't familiar with, figured the filter would help him when he's actually reviewing.

Comment: @Twelfth Sorry, I can't filter on that review page mentioned (the link), do you have anything extra over me, I just can't see? I think we're talking about different things: The ['Review Page'](http://stackoverflow.com/review) allows to gain badges for working on it, but has no filters besides those I mentioned.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - sorry, we are.  I was talking about when you've gone into a particular queue (like low quality), not the review page itself.

Comment: @Twelfth I still can't see how I'd apply a filter for e.g. the [Low quality posts](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5708303) quee.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Goto the review page, click the low quality posts.  It'll bring up the first question, above that you will see "Review | low quality posts filter" (on the same line as your badge progress and stats button).   The word filter is clickable and allows for tag filters.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - might as well clarify my 'makes test questions easy to recongnize' comment too.  The filter does not apply to test questions...I filter for sql, so any question that doesn't have the sql tag is a test question that I skip over.

Comment: Although I enjoyed reviewing for a while, it frustrated me more than I was willing to suffer so I stopped clicking the review button and instead just fix posts that I encounter when looking for answers and questions. I particularly disliked spending time on getting a post right only to find that some one else closed it/deleted it/changed it. I guess I am too slow :)

Comment: "And then there are also audits" can easily be interpreted as though audits are something you think is wrong with the review system. If this is the case, why? Audits take too much time from your real reviews? Audits make you feel policed?

Comment: I keep on hoping that eventually they will pay me for reviewing and I'll make a living out of that

Comment: Probably a similar impulse that makes people want to be moderators.

Comment: Some people just like seeing numbers going up! Ok, and I like helping out a site that's invaluable to my job, too (I remember before SO existed, when for an an average question the first result was (ugh!) expertsexchange.) But mostly it's the numbers going up thing.

Comment: I'm astonished you find audits demotivating!   I was absolutely delighted the first time I discovered there were audit questions.   I thought "wow, this site really rocks, they have gone to this trouble to make sure that everything is done well - I can be much surer now that people doing reviews are not just badge-button-clicking!"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you don't know what review action(s) should be taken for a particular post, skip it.

If you don't see any reason to review posts, or find that they are few/no posts that you're qualified to review (and you're not interested in learning how to review those posts) then just don't review.  While reviewing is nice, it is by no means a necessary activity.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is the most upvoted *or* the accepted answer, since it doesn't even answer the question of "why", but rather "should I?".

Comment: I agree on the skip. Don't be afraid to skip. Not sure? Skip. It's as simple as that.

Comment: I agree with "While reviewing is nice, it is by no means a necessary activity.".

Answer (score 18):

I agree that working on the [Review Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review)
isn't fun.

The only reasons I can imagine why people are motivated to do this is earning
one of the following badges to their profile:

- [Steward](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward) x 6
- [Reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1478/reviewer) x 6
- [Custodian](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2278/custodian) x 6

and to keep up the site's quality of course!

I'm actually going to that review page meanwhile only when I'm
**really very bored** with the actual activity appearing on my preferred
[Newest C++ Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) page
(you might want to see different tag filtered views).

---

I think providing more tag filters at the
[Review Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review), might be a good idea, to
increase interest for working on it. The mentioned
[feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262383) is a good idea IMHO.

Comment: Small note: one does *not* need to review anything to get `Copy Editor` (300 edits) or `Civic Duty` and (later on) `Electorate` (votes you've cast)! One earns them automatically simply by correct usage of the site. The `Custodian` badge is given for the first review-task in a review category, leaving `Reviewer` (at 250 reviews) to help you get into the category and *the ultimate 'goal': the golden `Steward` badge* (1000 reviews). And if one doesn't want the community saying 'you were only in it for the badge', you don't stop at 1000 reviews. BUT, reviewing also helps your learning experience!!

Comment: You can probably review and moderate more on that page than on the review tab :)

Answer (score 11):

I want to add 2 different/extra **motivations** to the other answers.

1. Some people want to *give back* and not 'leach' the community:
   asking/answering questions is not the only way one can help or
   participate in the community.
   Also, when a member doesn't have the time or doesn't feel qualified to contribute in the form of answers, they still get a visual indication (to the community) that they DO help out!
2. Governed by general rules and guidelines from SO, this Q&A site is largely moderated by the community.
   That makes SO a sort of *democracy*. (Especially regarding 'Close' and 'Reopen' *votes*.)

At some point in time there was (well, it still exists) another *very* popular Q&A platform; however it was moderated by a (relatively) small group of people (often/mostly on the publisher's payroll) who

- 'drowned' in the amount of content to moderate (as the site's popularity grew), leading to a mess over time
- weren't necessarily qualified to assess value of content
- very often disregarded their own 'rules' and 'community-ethic' in favor of pure financial motivations (asking questions usually earned the company cash (for example, disallowed exact duplicates were more than welcome), although one could earn a subscription (by answering questions) *payed* with their 'equivalent' of 'rep-points' effectively making it into a form of currency (as opposed to SO's rep)).
- often (sometimes quite harshly) disregarded valid complaints about their (colleague's) moderation (or the fundamental flaws of their ambiguous policy that inevitably would lead to the site's down-fall.)

Ultimately this both drove away their bread and butter (the experts who actually answered questions) and killed the idea of a central know-how DB. That kind of left a relatively small core of altruists that provided the knowhow/answers/solutions, who subsequently drowned in the 'workload'.
<sup>And no more bread and butter means no more paying customers. In a desperate attempt to save their income, the brilliant idea to bury their (rather huge) library of know-how under a lead dome (even google link-through access no longer displayed solutions) killed their google-ranking and subsequently ad-revenue.</sup>

This is what makes SO so fundamentally different: it basically solved the root(s) of the above problems. In order to do that one needs co-operation of the community, which in turn wants to be treated fair (and not subjected to a late-hour frustrated judgment-call from *one* person (with optional agenda)), which can only happen in an *open democracy*.  Heck, we even have *meta*..

Also, the ability to improve/update (links for example) content on our 'shared programmers notebook' is an incredible valuable feature, but it can only exist if we share the resulting workload of validating the edits!
I'm grateful for other peers safeguarding (my) content, expressing that gratefulness *can* be simply done by sharing some of that workload.

The **benefits** are probably the same as the reasons for voting in a democratic country; ultimately a form of *self-interest*.
I want SO to continue to survive and flourish so that I can still access it's (growing) wealth tomorrow!
<sup>I remember there was a day that SO was down (and it was known it would be for the rest of the day) and there were a lot of reports of programmers going home for the rest of the day.</sup>
Also, if nobody with the same preferences and ideas as mine 'speaks up', nobody would know those ideas might even reflect a democratic majority.

Comment: lol, in fact, your answer better describes my reasoning, then my own answer (which is meant to be 0.75-serious anyway). You've made me recall that wanting to *give back* something after anonymously getting help from SO many times was actually the only reason I joined :-)

Answer (score 6):

To make the review items more relevant to your knowledge and experience, add filters as suggested in the comments to avoid looking at things you're not familiar with:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Note that the word **filter** is a link that displays the dialog above to allow filters to be added to review queues. The filters include tags you want to see and in this case close reasons, as it's the close review queue.

For me personally, this drastically improved my reviewing experience as I had to click skip a lot less!

**NOTE: This filtering is only available in the Close Votes Review queue for 3k+ users**

Comment: Wow. I've done 1.036 reviews now, but somehow I managed to miss the _filter_ link all this time, until I've seen your screenshot :D

Comment: @AJPerez Same; this is gonna be such a boon!

Comment: The OP doesn't have enough rep to use the Close Vote queue, and that's the only queue with this feature.

Comment: @Servy My bad, wasn't aware / forgot about that.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's questions "what motivates users to review? How do they benefit from this?"

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I was aiming to answer this part of his question: _I found that there are posts about things that I'm not familiar with..._ I guess since Servy's comment identified the issue with this post it doesn't help to a massive degree, but it seems a few people have benefited from the answer none the less.

Comment: @Servy just checked, every queue has the filters available to enable filtering by tag

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I take that back, just checked and all queues enable filtering by tag, so I'd argue it's useful to the OP on the point that I previously mentioned.

Comment: I'm not saying your answer isn't useful, just that it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot the "question" is tagged "discussion", please have a read of what that means: [discussion tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion/info)

Comment: Discuss all you want, you still haven't addressed the question as to what motivates reviewers to review. There's really nothing more for me to say about that, I've already said the same thing three times.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot well let's agree to disagree and leave it at that

Answer (score 4):

Some people can't handle mess in front of their eyes. The definition of *mess*, depending on the person of course, can include any deviation from *the rules*, where rules cover things from spelling, to general SO policies, to even broader principles. Whether they want to make the world a better place, or they just can't cope with their, colloquially meant, inner [OCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder) or [OCPD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_personality_disorder) (as [Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray) pointed out) they just do it, whenever they see an opportunity.

Such people are motivated by the reduced anxiety level, after they, in general, *fix* something, which includes reviewing, fixing typos, etc..

If you feel that this answer may, at least partially, describe you, then you may want to test yourself with the [online version of the Yale-Brown Obsessive Compulsive](http://psychology-tools.com/yale-brown-obsessive-compulsive-scale) test.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out the difference between OCD and [OCPD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_personality_disorder). Essentially, while those with OCD see their obsessive and compulsive behaviors as undesirable and unnatural, those with OCPD see them as highly desirable attributes, with positive outcomes. Most of the reviewers are probably best characterized by the latter. :-)

Comment: I think this answer is more about *editing* than reviewing (which includes voting to close/reopen/delete/etc *and* safeguarding content against invalid/malicious edits). (PS: I find that OCD test insane and in no way relating to fixing up real code-mess *in order to make the question readable to both yourself AND other experts* (which in turn helps solicit more and better answers, thus increasing overall quality on SO)).

Comment: @GitaarLAB Perhaps it's because you don't perceive non-zero numbers of questions in a queue as something to *fix* :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks, that's interesting!

Comment: @BartoszKP: deal, might I suggest to add that example to your answer?

Comment: @GitaarLAB Not sure what example you're referring to, but if you think it's an improvement then go ahead, no problem :)

Comment: @BartoszKP: I meant: '*fix* something (like the non-zero numbers of questions in a review-queue), '